# Настройка сервера с несколькими приложениями

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Нужно на одном виртуальном серевере (*ubuntu* c *nginx*) установить нескотько приложений(*jenkins*, *wiki*, *gitlab*, *youtrack*)

Все это уже установлено, но на своих портах.

Вопрос в том, можно ли настроить *nginx* такЁ чтобы он пробрасывал на эти приложения не по порту а по поддомену:

```
jenkins.site.com
wiki.site.com
gitlab.site.com -> site.com:8111
youtrack.site.com -> site.com:8112
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name gitlab.site.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://site.com:8111/;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name youtrack.site.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://site.com:8112/;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Каждый блок [`server`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) отвечает за свой домен/поддомен. При помощи [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/server_names.html) указывается имя сервера. При обращении по домену/поддомену, `nginx` выбирает блок `server` с наиболее подходящим именем. А далее при помощи [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) происходит проксирование запроса на другой домен или, в Вашем случае, порт.